# Can I install latest version of mPDF without SSH

Tags: mpdf

The doc of the latest version of mPDF on [github](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) suggest the only way to install it is by using composer. But how to do on a shared host without SSH access?

Is there an other way to install it? Or will it be? Or should I just continue to use the older version still [available for download](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) (but it looks no longer supported and no longer compatible with the latest version of PHP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the main mPDF Github page is for development version. There still are [ready-to-use packages for version 6.1.0](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases/tag/v6.1.0) which can be uploaded and used as-is.

However, I would recommend installing mPDF via composer locally and then transfer the whole local installation to your server via FTP or whatever you use.

As the composer is de-facto standard for package management now, future versions of mPDF will not provide those pre-prepared packages anymore.